# Prove that map is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Delta^{n+1}= \{(x_0,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : 0 \leq x_0 \leq...\leq x_n \leq 1 \}$, consider the maps $d_0,...,d_n: \Delta^{n+1} \to \Delta^n \times I$ given by $$d_i(x_0,...,x_n)=((x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n),x_i).$$ How can I see that $\text{Im}(d_i)$ is homeomorphic to $\Delta^{n+1}$ and that $\Delta^n \times I = \cup_{i=0}^n \text{Im}(d_i)$, I am not really sure where to start here.

Comment: I am new to this site I don't know why my question is being down voted, if I asked the question in a wrong manner then please enlighten me instead.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're getting downvoted either.  However, it would help if you provided a bit more context to your question.  You've said that "you're not really sure where to start here", but what have you tried?  What ideas do you think might be relevant?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I see nothing wrong with your question.

Comment: As for the content of the question: it would help to try to characterize the image of $d_i$ in a manner similar to your definition of $\Delta^{n+1}$.  That is, it is helpful to observe that 
$$
\operatorname{Im}(d_i) = \{((x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}),x_n) : (x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}) \in \Delta^{n} \text{ and } x_{i-1} \leq x_n \leq x_{i} \}
$$

Comment: Does $(x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n)$ mean that $x_i$ is being removed from that $n+1$-tuple? Judging by Omnomnomnom's comment, it seems to, but if that's a standard convention, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: I have done that but in a slightly different way, I wrote $\text{Im}(d_i)= \{((x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n),x_i) : \{(x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n) \in \Delta^n , x_{i-1} \leq x_i \leq x_{i+1} \}$, is this wrong? I don't quite agree with your characterisation.

Comment: @NickPavlov Yes.

Comment: he just re-labelled them, $i \rightarrow n$, $k+1 \rightarrow k$ for $k \geq i$

Comment: I think the maps are rather straightforward, $f_i: \text{Im}(d_i) \to \Delta^{n+1}$ is given by $((x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n),x_i) \mapsto (x_0,...,x_i,...,x_n)$ and the inverse function $g_i$ by $(x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto ((x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_n),x_i)$ but I don't really know how to prove that they are continuous.

Comment: Your characterization is technically correct, but not particularly clear if we're trying to understand what the set looks like. For instance, I claim that with my characterization, it is very easy to see that the union of the images gives us $\Delta^n \times I$, as desired.

Comment: I also think it's easier to see that the inverse function is continuous if we write it as
$$
((x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}),x_n) \mapsto (x_0,\dots,x_{i-1},x_n,x_i,\dots,x_{n-1})
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see what you mean. My first though was that the function and its inverse obviously are continuous since they are continuous in each component, is this correct?

Comment: @user502427 exactly.

Comment: Can you explain the way you re-labell them? I don't really get that part.